# okhttp3.internal.framed.StreamResetException: stream was reset: CANCEL

Tags: okhttp

I'm getting secret from Azure KeyVault through rest api. At backend, I'm using the azure-keyvault-client which is using retrofit and okhttp3 at behind. My app has been running well for a long time. Now it shows up the exceptions suddenly. Each time the exceptions happens, I  restarts the app. Then the exceptions are gone. Everything looks good. What will be the reason that "stream was cancelled"?

Below is the full stack trace.

[image]

I have tried to remote debug the app. I found that the exception is thrown when call FramedStream.closeInternal(). The HttpEngine tries to close but source.finished = false and sink.finished = true.

Comment: I have tried to read the code of okhttp. But I still cannot figure out in which situation the ErrorCode CANCEL will be assigned to the response source stream.

Answer (score 0):

It could either be a local cancel of the stream, or from the server.  You can use HTTP/2 Frame logging so see if it's coming from the server.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/debug_logging/#http2-frame-logging

Does the problem persist until restart?  If so it's possible that the server is expecting you or OkHttp to close the connection after the cancel, but that isn't expected in that case.  So best to debug the frames and then discuss with the server team.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-testing-support/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/OkHttpDebugLogging.kt

```
  fun enableHttp2() = enable(Http2::class)

  fun enableTaskRunner() = enable(TaskRunner::class)

  fun enable(loggerClass: String) {
    val logger = Logger.getLogger(loggerClass)
    if (configuredLoggers.add(logger)) {
      logger.addHandler(ConsoleHandler().apply {
        level = Level.FINE
        formatter = object : SimpleFormatter() {
          override fun format(record: LogRecord) =
            String.format("[%1\$tF %1\$tT] %2\$s %n", record.millis, record.message)
        }
      })
      logger.level = Level.FINEST
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried to remote debug the app. I found that the exception is thrown when call FramedStream.closeInternal(). The HttpEngine tries to close but source.finished = false and sink.finished = true